# Get current location without using delegate didUpdateLocations in CLLocationManager using swift 3 or 4?

Tags: swift3, mkmapview

Is there a way to get current location without calling delegate didUpdateLocations in CLLocationManager using swift 3 or 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn’t call didUpdateLocation: but rather requestLocation() which would update the user location then call didUpdateLocation, but that’s besides the point...

The “location” instance property might be what you are looking for but as the documentation states, you aren’t guaranteed of it being recent and you should check the time stamp.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1423687-location

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your quick response, now I can get my current location when I initialized the CLLocationManager(), with this locationManager.location!.coordinate.latitude

Comment: Be careful with the ! as location can return nil if you request if before a location is ever retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mapView.userLocation.coordinate`.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapview/1452459-userlocation